# ORA-00904 INVALID IDENTIFIER with Inner Join

Tags: sql, oracle10g, inner-join, ora-00904

I'm trying to do an inner join between 3 tables in an ERD I created.  I've successfully built 3 - 3 layer sub-queries using these tables, and when I researched this issue, I can say that in my DDL, I didn't use double quotes so the columns aren't case sensitive.  Joins aren't my strong suite so any help would be much appreciated.  This is the query im putting in, and the error it's giving me.  All of the answers I've seen when people do inner joins they use the syntax, 'INNER JOIN' but I wasn't taught this? Is my method still okay?

```
SQL> 
SELECT  regional_lot.location, 
        rental_agreement.vin, 
        rental_agreement.contract_ID 
FROM regional_lot, 
     rental_agreement 
WHERE regional_lot.regional_lot_id = vehicle1.regional_lot_ID 
  AND vehicle1.vin = rental_agreement.vin;


                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "VEHICLE1"."VIN": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you don't have `vehicle1` in your `FROM` list.

You should give ANSI joins a try. For one, they're a lot more readable and you don't pollute your `WHERE` clause with join conditions

```
SELECT regional_lot.location, rental_agreement.vin, rental_agreement.contract_ID
FROM rental_agreement
INNER JOIN vehicle1
    ON rental_agreement.vin = vehicle1.vin
INNER JOIN regional_lot
    ON vehicle1.regional_lot_ID = regional_lot.regional_lot_id;
```

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try, I was under the impression, you only had to list tables in the "FROM" if you are listing information from that table after the "select" part of the statement.

Comment: @MatthewClenney All referenced tables need to be included via the `FROM` clause or via joins

Comment: So your statement worked, and it is much easier to read!  The only thing i'm confused about is it seems like you spread out the "from" table sources across the whole query.  Do you just "INNER JOIN <table_name> ON <table_you're moving from>.PK = <table_you're moving to>.FK ?

Comment: @MatthewClenney Not sure what you mean by *spread out* but the ordering of the left / right operands for an equality comparison `ON` condition do not matter.

Comment: I meant that instead of saying FROM <table1>, <table2>, <table3> WHERE etc. they are referenced when each inner join is mentioned.  And okay I appreciate the help.

Comment: Using the `JOIN` syntax meets the ANSI standard. Putting all the tables in the `FROM` clause performs a *natural join* anyway. See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:13430766143199

Comment: @Phil, `FROM t1, t2, t3` etc does a cross join, not a natural join.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Ah yup, it's been a while ;)

Answer (score 1):

you foret add table vehicle1 to section "from" in your query:

```
from regional_lot, rental_agreement, vehicle1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed to join the table `VEHICLE1`. Also you can use alias on table names.
Try like this,

```
SELECT regional_lot.location,
       rental_agreement.vin,
       rental_agreement.contr act_ID
FROM   regional_lot a,
       rental_agreement b,
       vehicle1 c
WHERE  a.regional_lot_id = c.regional_lot_ID
AND    c.vin                 = b.vin;
```